# FromJSON custom for custom type

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

The newest version of Data.Aeson changed the way that ToJSON and FromJSON work for simple types like:

```
data Permission = Read | Write
```

It used to be that the generic call:

```
instance ToJSON Permission where
```

...Would create JSON that looked like {"Read":[]} or {"Write":[]}.

But now it creates:
`{tag:"Read",contents:"[]"}`

Which makes sense but breaks code I have written.  I wrote a toJSON part by hand to give the correct looking stuff but writing the fromJSON is confusing me.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you'd want to/fromJSON instances for this data type in the first place. This data type represents a constant more-so than an abstract type. I could see this being used as a part of a larger data structure that had a given permission, i.e. `{..., "permission" : "read"}`. Care to elaborate on how it is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value contained in the `Object` constructor for `Data.Aeson.Value` is just a strict `HashMap`, we can extract the keys from it and make a decision based on that.  I tried this and it worked pretty well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module StackOverflow where

import Data.Aeson
import Control.Monad
import Data.HashMap.Strict (keys)

data Permission = Read | Write

instance FromJSON Permission where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        let ks = keys v
        in case ks of
            ["Read"] -> return Read
            ["Write"] -> return Write
            _ -> mzero
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

You can test it with `decode "{\"Read\": []}" :: Maybe Permission`.  The `mzero` in `parseJSON` ensures that if something else is passed in, it'll just return `Nothing`.  Since you seem to want to only check if there is a single key matching one of your two permissions, this is pretty straightforward and will properly return `Nothing` on all other inputs.

Comment: Thanks this looks nicer than what I did and I will change it.

Also, I looked through Data.Aeson and saw using <|> to handle the alternatives which also worked nicely.

Comment: @TallerGhostWalt Whatever works best for you.  I think either implementation would be approximately equivalent in speed, and it'd probably be pretty readable too.  I'm certainly no expert with Aeson, so there might be a better way to do this still, but I wouldn't worry about it too much.  You could shorten it with just `case keys v of` though, if you wanted to save a line.  I just prefer not to have an expression in a case, it always seems messy to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could control how datatype with all nullary constructors is encoded using `allNullaryToStringTag` field on `Data.Aeson.Options`. Set it to `True` and it will be encoded simply as string.

```
import Data.Aeson.Types (Options (..), defaultOptions)

data Permission = Read | Write

$(deriveToJSON (defaultOptions {allNullaryToStringTag = True}) ''Permission)
```

Take a look at [`Options` definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t%3aOptions), it contains other handy fields.